# Error 0x800f0922 when installing IIS on Windows 10: "The changes couldn't be completed."

Tags: windows, iis

On a new installation of Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1703 I tried turning on the IIS feature, default options selected, via "Turn Windows features on or off," but ran into the error shown below:

[image: Windows Features error]

I then attempted to install the feature using DISM. I opened an admin command prompt and entered:

```
Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /All
```

This should be the same as installing the default set of features for IIS. This also failed with the same error code 0x800f0922.

Lastly, I tried selecting IIS elements one piece at a time from the "Turn Windows features on and off" menu. This worked until I tried installing "HTTP Errors," which produced the window above again.

Running this command:

```
Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /All
```

resulted in the same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Touch the file `C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US\401-1.htm`, creating any missing directories in the path, then run the installer again.**

More info:

I viewed the log file for DISM located at `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log` and found the following set of lines for the error:

```
2017-10-09 13:43:28, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4280 TID=14940 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0922)
2017-10-09 13:43:28, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4280 TID=14940 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x800f0922)
2017-10-09 13:43:28, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4280 TID=14940 Failed ProcessChanges. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x800f0922)
2017-10-09 13:43:28, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4280 TID=14940 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0922)
2017-10-09 13:43:28, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=4280 TID=14940 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2017-10-09 13:43:28, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=800F0922
```

Following the recommendation, I checked the CBS log located at `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` and found the following line with the same timestamp:

```
2017-10-09 13:43:28, Error                 CSI    00000096 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND #5294871# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile(flags = (AllowSharingViolation|AllowAccessDenied), handle = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (FILE_GENERIC_READ|DELETE|WRITE_DAC|WRITE_OWNER|FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_WRITE_EA|FILE_APPEND_DATA|FILE_WRITE_DATA|0x00000040), oa = @0x92431fdd18->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[38]'\??\C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US\401-1.htm'; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0x92431fdd78, as = (null), fa = (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL), sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE), cd = 5, co = (FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE|FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|0x00004000), eab = NULL, eal = 0, disp = Invalid)
```

I was able to determine that it was looking for the path `C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US\401-1.htm` and couldn't find it. Sure enough, that path did not exist at all.

First, I tried testing permissions by giving the user object Everyone full control access to inetpub. I know, not ideal, but it was worth it to test it. I ran that DISM command again to add HttpErrors, but still failed. Finally I just created the directories `custerr` and `en-US`, and a blank text file called `401-1.htm`, and tried DISM one last time. The folder instantly populated with the rest of the HTTP error pages and the installation completed.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: On my case, after I've created the `C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US\401-1.htm` it was also necessary to create another file `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm`. After that it installed IIS successfully.

Comment: +1 not for the solution itself but just for sharing this information so that hopefully the next guy can just get on with things.

Comment: Amazingly, after 3 days of searching. Creating the two files above and their paths allowed me to install IIS on Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

I had to uninstall Windows Process Activation Service feature first, reboot, then I was able to install IIS properly.

Answer (score 2):

I created the two directory paths / empty files with no change. But - I had selected to install -only- IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatability. When I additionally selected to install the IIS Management Console the procedure successfully ran to completion.

Comment: Thanks this was my issue as well

Answer (score 1):

Disabling McAfee solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error but was able to get IIS installed just by persevering with Control Panel | Programs | Turn Windows features on and off. When I first launched this, if I just selected the top-level Internet Information Services, as I've done with every other computer and every other version of Windows, I got this response repeatedly. With or without my antivirus running (which in my case is ZoneAlarm and MalwareBytes).

I got around this by expanding the IIS entry in the feature list, and just installing a few of the individual items at a time. My goal at the start of this was just to hone in on exactly what the problem was, although I found that every sub-component installed successfully.

**Pros:** everything installed OK, and only one of the subcomponents required me to reboot (and even that might have been because I also took the opportunity to get rid of IE11). And I suppose it's good that I didn't have to track down the actual MS error which caused this. **Cons:** there are probably 30-odd subcomponents nestling in three or four tiers under the main IIS option. Even though it all worked in the end, it took a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by expanding the IIS entry in the feature list, and installing each individual item at a time

Comment: You can see I tried that approach in my original question, but it failed for me. Glad it worked for someone, though!

Answer (score 1):

I run into this error while trying to install Request Monitor feature of IIS. In order to troubleshoot it, I would recommend checking:

- CBS logs (C:\Windows\Logs\CBS)
- DISM logs (C:\Windows\Logs\DISM)
- ApplicationHost.config file (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config)
- The output of Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth command
- Procmon logs (Use Process Monitor tool)

In my case Procmon logs showed `PARSE_ERROR_INFO` while reading **applicationHost.config** file which was corrupted. Reinstalling IIS solved the issue. Source: [0x800f0922 Update IIS-RequestMonitor of package IIS-WebServer-Core-Package failed](https://port135.com/2019/11/08/update-iis-requestmonitor-package-0x800f0922/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, version 1909, I had to first install the "IIS Management Console" feature.
Then I was able to add the features under the IIS 6 Management Compatibility folder without getting the 0x800f0922 error.

I was able to add both [IIS 6 Management Console] and [IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility] at the same time.

Then I was able to install the program that needed these as prerequisites, Exchange Management Console 2010 bayy-bee! Yey Yey.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me - like you, I was not trying to install full IIS, just trying to install the IIS 6 console and metabase compatibility to prep for the Exchange 2010 management tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a Windows Server 2012 R2. In my case it solved after running all the pending updates on windows update (even the optional ones, it was one of them)

Answer (score 0):

All config files in the IIS folder has to be present too
Location:
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\